# how i can fill 2 pivot table by 1 request laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have table Users

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guarded = ['group_c', 'group_s', 'categories'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

this table have relation 'many to many' to  2 anoter tables: Group

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

and Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function Users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

I take data from Post request, and put them to Users table ,but 'group'
field I write into 'group_user' pivot table, in my controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function create_user(CrateNewUser $request)
    {
        //dd(Request::all());
        if (Request::input('user_type') == '1') {
            $groups = Request::input('group_c');
            $categories = Request::input('categories');
            User::create(Request::all())->groups()->attach($groups);
        } elseif (Request::input('user_type') == '2') {
            $groups = Request::input('group_s');
            $categories = Request::input('categories');
            User::create(Request::all())->groups()->attach($groups);
        }

        return $this->manage_users();
    }
}
```

but I need also write data from another Post field 'categories' to another Pivot table categories_user by one sql request, how i can do that ?

Comment: Is `CrateNewUser` a Form Request?

Comment: Your ->groups()->attach($groups) is trying to attach a field from the form. you should make a Group model first, perhaps with Group::find($groups)

Comment: @Mei If `Request::input('categories')` returns a single id or an array of ids then no you don't.

Comment: @RossWilson , yes CreateNewUser is validator, all I need, is do the same thing for categories as for a group, and I think it need to be in one request , cause if I type same request for cat as for groups lower, the I get an error, that in my db alredy exist this user

Comment: Request::input('group_c') - what does that field contain? IDs of groups that should be linked?

Comment: @ jedrzej.kurylo, yes, this is array of Id, and it's work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to link user to a set of groups/category using their IDs you need to use **sync()** method. It will update the pivot table so that only synced records are linked.

The following should do the trick:

```
$user = User::create(Request::all());
$user->groups()->sync($groups);
$user->categories()->sync($categories);
```